# How to keep alive services (nginx and lxc) installed by dokku?

Tags: dokku

I've just installed dokku in a brand new ubuntu 16.04 box with 2GB ram memory. I've also added a very simple app to make sure dokku is working.

It works fine for a while but, after some minutes, nginx service stops working along with one container for the app I used for testing.

Is there any good way to keep these services up and running?

Comment: this is not a normal behaviour, if you start an app, the server will keep running after you manuallly set it off. So maybe there is a problem with the app you uploaded to your server that is stopping it

Comment: This is the app I'm using to test: https://github.com/matiasmm/hello-world .    This issue is being followed here: https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/3202